# Conda env downgrade nvcc

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, conda, nvcc

I'm trying to install/downgrade to nvcc 10.2 in my conda environment (anaconda3) as it is needed by the version of PyTorch (1.10.2) that I'm using.

I have a nvcc 11.7 installation outside of conda, which my conda env is automatically using.

I was able to install and supersede cudatoolkit 10.2 successfully, but that doesn't come with nvcc.

So `torch.version.cuda` gives me `10.2` but `nvcc -V` gives me `11.7`.

Internet mainly suggests installing cudatoolkit-dev from conda-forge as it seems to come with nvcc but there is no cudatoolkit-dev 10.2 to be found with

```
conda search cudatoolkit-dev --channel conda-forge
```

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, a GTX1080 with driver 515.43.04.

---

Edit: Correct solution seems to be installing CUDA in conda through

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit-dev=xxx
```

I had to downgrade PyTorch so I could use CUDA 10.1, for which there is a conda-forge package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could understand how CudaToolkit, NVCC, and the PyTorch version you installed are related.
Wikipedia says

> Nvidia CUDA Compiler is a proprietary compiler by Nvidia intended for use with CUDA. CUDA code runs on both the CPU and GPU. NVCC separates these two parts and sends host code to a C compiler like GCC or Intel C++ Compiler or Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler, and sends the device code to the GPU.

you can have multiple CUDA versions installed on your computer at the same time but only one could be used (the one that is on the set path)

Conda creates a new virtual environment to package your code libraries such has python == 3.6 torch == 10.2 etc. It helps you to have different versions of PyTorch and other libraries so that you can switch between those environments when required (for example for different projects you may have different torch versions NumPy versions etc.). **But conda can not change CUDA, CudaToolkit paths**

Solution:
If you have installed CUDA, CUDA Toolkit you need to put that on the path here is an example how

```
# PATH FOR CUDA 10.0 being used by tensorflow 1.13
#export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:$PATH"
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64

#write for CUDA libs 11.0
#export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin
#export CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda-11.0
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64

# PATH FOR CUDA 10.2
#export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:$PATH"
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/extras/CUPTI/l$


#cuda 11.4
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64
```

[image]

I have multiple CUDA versions installed and I uncomment whenever a specific version is required in bashrc file.

in ubuntu, you can open it with

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

on Windows maybe you need to add it in environment variables please check the NVIDIA guide for that and change your paths as required.

Comment: Same as for questions: Please don't post images of text. Copy/paste it into your answer please, at it is much more readable, more accessible and can be copy/pasted

Comment: sure thanks for your suggestion I am updating :)

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! I too thought about installing CUDA 10.2 and managing by commenting PATH but there is no CUDA 10.2 for Ubuntu 22.04.

I got it to work by using an older version of PyTorch that was using CUDA 10.1, which there is a cudatoolkit-dev package for!

After all im not sure about ur statement that conda cannot change CUDA paths, cuz I now have 11.7 on non conda envs and 10.1 in conda env.

Comment: @Thilo I appreciate your efforts. Conda can only switch between different PyTorch versions. For CUDA libraries you will still need to change path yourself for those versions of pytorch.

Comment: @MahmoodHussain That seems to be not true! I successfully use cuda and nvcc in version 10.1 even though I have neither installed this CUDA version on my system, nor have I edited the PATH in .bashrc. You only need to install cudatoolkit-dev from conda-forge, as I have edited in my original post. Might be possible though, that I'm misinterpreting what u are saying.

Comment: That means you would only have CUDA 10.1 installed and that is already on path.

Comment: Nah, I have 11.7 on path.. conda has its own path

Answer (score -1):

`nvcc` is mapped to what `CUDA` version exists in your environment path. This means, that when you install `cudatoolkit` through `conda`, you won't be able to get `nvcc` unless you have installed `CUDA` manually either through `apt` or `NVIDIA`'s website. You can validate that using this command: `which nvcc`, and this command should show some path under `/usr/local/` not under your `conda` environment.

When you install `cudatoolkit`, you are installing `CUDA` version within your `python` environment which `torch` is mapped and has access. That's why `torch.version.cuda` gives a different version than `nvcc --version`.